# Response based on user input, dynamic reponses

Tags: dialogflow-es

Good day,

I am currently trying to create an intent that is able to put out responses depending on the user input. (The chatbot should be implemented on a website later)

Let's say we have an entity called cars with three entries: "Volkswagen" "Audi" "Ford". 
Now when the user types in something with e.g. Audi in it, the response will correspond to this. Something like this: If Audi then give this response, if Ford then this response.

I couldn't find anything helpful yet.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Intents represent *what the user says* and not how you handle this or how you reply. Although Dialogflow does offer the ability to respond to Intents, these aren't based on specific values that may appear in parameters.

There are, however, a variety of ways you can handle what you're doing, based on the rest of what you're trying to do.

**Multiple Intents**

One solution is to create an Intent for each type of thing that the user may talk about. You could then put the response you want for each in the response section of that Intent.

This is probably a bad approach, but may be useful in some ways. It requires you to duplicate phrases between the different Intents, which leads to a lot of duplication. On the upside, it does let you vary the replies, and truly represents the Intent of what the user is trying to say.

**Using Parameters with Fulfillment**

A better approach is to have a single Intent with many phrases representing what the users can ask. These phrases would have parameters of your Entity Type.

You can then enable Fulfillment for this Intent and write a Fulfillment webhook for the Intent that would look a the value of the parameter and send back an appropriate reply.

**Using Parameters with DetectIntent**

Since your ultimate goal is to embed this on a website, it may be more appropriate to have your website show something different based on what the user has said. (For example to show a picture of the car in another pane or links to different pages, to use your example of cars.)

In this case, your chat client (or a proxy) would  be calling the [DetectIntent API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent). You can structure your Intent similar to above, with parameters of the Entity Type, and the reply that is sent to your client would contain the Intent along with the value of the parameter. Your client then can check the value of the parameter and change the display accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for taking you time to reply!

Comment: The DetectIntent API sounds quite interesting since the chatbot should also be able to navigate on the website and display links. But how exactly do I use it?

Comment: The details of using DetectIntent depend on a lot of details about how you implement your web client. I've added a link to the documentation, and there is a lot more documentation available from there. StackOverflow works best when there are specific problems to address, so you may want to try implementing something this way and, if you encounter problems, post as many details as you can (code, Intents, Entities, etc) to a new question explaining the problem you're having. If an answer has helped you, upvoting and/or accepting it is always appreciated.